# error in running a web application on tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am currently converting my Java project written under Eclipse to a web application and trying to run on tomcat server. I have converted the project into a maven module, changed its project facets and other requirements to make it a web app. I have put my project.cfg.xml file under WEB-INF and included  deployment to web.xml file. When i run my browser and point to "http://localhost:8080/manager/html", i am able to see my deployed war file. But it says running = false and when i click on my project, it shows me

```
HTTP Status 404 - /myproject/

type Status report

message /myproject/

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

I faced the same problem in running sample programs from "quickstart" also.

Comment: Are you sure that your Tomcat is running?

Comment: tomcta is running but the app isn't. Just start it, if it fails to start read the error messages.

Comment: thanks.i have an error stating "Exception in starting filter"...i am working on it.any idea regarding the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the tomcat console . Surely, there are some errors being thrown at the application start-up, due to which it's not starting.

Comment: yes i do have an error stating "Exception in starting filter"

Comment: i am not able to understand the cause of the exception. it says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter".any idea why would that be happening?

Comment: Also,when on my browser, when i try "http://localhost:8080/manager/html", i am able to deploy the my war file.But its running state is false and when i try to click on "start" button, i get a message as "FAIL - Application at context path /SimpleApp5 could not be started". My log says "Exception in starting filter". which is dependent on which or these two errors independent? I tried searching related queries, but none works for me. Any idea?

Comment: i have added a dependency of servlet-api in my pom.xml, but that too does not correct it!

Comment: you probably need to add  a jar to your lib folder..Search for jar containing that class and try adding it.

Comment: aaw yess!, i am able to do it now.my mistake was that i had placed the web.xml file in the wrong path.now i have written a simple servlet to test and able to run my application on server directly from eclipse and also outside it on the browser...thank you so much for the help extended.

Answer (score 2):

You should read $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out  This log records the lifecycle of web applications.  You should be able to find the part where it attempts to start your web application and it is most likely throwing some errors at that location.